# how can I compute a roughness map without any 3D softwares?

Tags: pbr

Recently, I want to use a roughness map to get better rendering results.
Most information on the internet is about the operation of 3D software.
So, how can I generate a roughness map of my own 3D mesh?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the major photo/image editing software programs can be used to generate a roughness map. It is usually best just to search google with something like, "How to create a roughness map using xyz." Where xyz is photoshop or some other popular image editor. If you can narrow you question down a little with the software you have, or the images you have and how they are generated then it makes it easier to give a specific answer to your question.

Comment: I mean, how can I generate the roughness map by my owen codes in C++/Python.

Comment: @jacktsang Maybe you should edit your question and add this information there.

Comment: even gimp can use a map with noise values. 
More more pliability, the best is to use https://www.shadertoy.com/ ;-)